# post apocalyptic movie with eagle-helmet

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

The movie might be from the 80's. I only remember (barely) some few scenes of the beginning. It's located in a wasteland, a guy on a motorcycle who wears a helmet decorated as an eagle comes to a place where other guys on motorbikes play some kind of Polo with a human head or skull.

Comment: I was thinking [*The Blood of Heroes*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoz4mU_MHtQ) but it's not mounted on motorbikes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is [*The Last Border*](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_last_border)

[image: Movie poster for The Last Border]
Note the eagle helmet at the upper left.

> It is the year 2009, and civilization has almost perished on the planet, choked to death by pollution. The only place it survives is in the frigid far north. There, the few survivors are governed by a harsh military government, and dissenters quickly find themselves rounded up by the murderous Duke (Jurgen Prochnow). The picture opens as Jake (Jolyon Baker), a captive of Duke's, manages to escape. He helps rescue a peddler (Matti Pellonpaa) from the aftereffects of a motorcycle accident, and in gratitude the merchant helps Jake get free of his handcuffs. Another escapee is an amnesiac but capable woman (Fanny Bastien), who becomes a romantic partner of sorts, as they almost inadvertently manage to bring down the murderous enforcer.

The Duke is the character with the eagle helmet.

### Trailer

Found with a search for `post apocalyptic film eagle helmet`